# adding pattern in contact form 7 text

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I have a query related to Pattern="[A-Za-z]" to be set in text* your-name in Contact form 7

When this form works, even clients send numbers ( fake name ) in contact form. Which i want to block and let them only to enter there name alphabetically only .

Thank you in advance for suggestions and ideas.

My current code for text tag is as below.

```
<label> Your Name (Required)
<p>[text* your-name placeholder "Name"] </p></label>
```

Answer (score 0):

suppose your contact form field is this , with id 'firstname'

```
[text text-703 id:firstname placeholder "first name"]
```

then put this script in footer.php or header.php file, just change the id of the field.

like

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#firstname').keydown(function (e) {
                  if (e.shiftKey || e.ctrlKey || e.altKey) {
                      e.preventDefault();
                  } else {
                      var key = e.keyCode;
                      if (!((key == 8) || (key == 32) || (key == 46) || (key >= 35 && key <= 40) || (key >= 65 && key <= 90))) {
                          e.preventDefault();
                      }
                  }
              });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: i tried , but i think contact form 7 dont work such script. Kindly suggest.Here below how code is looking now.
https://prnt.sc/jowkq7

Comment: updated the answer . Do not put the script in contact form 7

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom filter for validation

```
add_filter( 'wpcf7_validate_text*', 'custom_text_validation_filter', 20, 2 );

function custom_text_validation_filter( $result, $tag ) {
    if ( 'your-name' == $tag->name ) {
        // matches any utf words with the first not starting with a number
        $re = '/^[^\p{N}][\p{L}]*/i';

        if (!preg_match($re, $_POST['your-name'], $matches)) {
            $result->invalidate($tag, "This is not a valid name!" );
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```